# mysqldump created dump is uncomplete

Tags: typo3, mysql

A TYPO3 installation has 57 tables in it's database named `typo3`.
Creating a dump using the `mysqldump` program by the command

```
mysqldump --host=127.0.0.1 --password=<PASSWORD> --protocol=tcp --port=3306 --user=<ROOT-USER> --lock-all-tables --databases typo3 > dump.sql
```

contains only 47 tables.
The same result occurs if the database connection is done via socket and also if the "--lock-all-tables" option is left out.
How to make a complete dump containing all the tables?

The missing tables are

- `index_config`
- `index_debug`
- `index_fulltext`
- `index_grlist`
- `index_phash`
- `index_rel`
- `index_section`
- `index_stat_search`
- `index_stat_word`
- `index_words`

Comment: Did you check the SQL-File, if that tables are missing there too? Are these tables views of a different database? I guess it is not a problem with that command.

Comment: Thanks to Urs and Viktor Livakivskyi for their intention to help! The problem was caused by an individual script triggered by cron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Urs and Viktor Livakivskyi for their intention to help! The problem was caused by an individual script triggered by cron.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, why all the index_* tables are not dumped with mysqldump, but I can suggest you to use [SypexDumper](http://sypex.net/en/). In most of the cases, when mysqldump or phpMyAdmin dumps were not possible, it saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

I use this for dumping: mysqldump -u server_dbuser -p -h localhost server_db > dbdump.sql

Have you tried from phpmyadmin?

Are the index_ tables needed, or can the be rebuilt anytime anyway?